# Where can I find the points per game throughout many NBA seasons?

Tags: basketball, statistics, nba

Where can I find the points per game (of both teams) throughout many NBA seasons?

To illustrate my point, what I mean is something like:

- 2000/01 average points per NBA game: 200;
- 2001/02 average points per NBA game: 210;
- 2002/03 average points per NBA game: 205;

so on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On [basketball-reference.com](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_stats.html) you can find many stats on NBA matches.

In the colum Points in the Game section you can find data you need (see the picture below and use x2 coefficient)

[image: Points per game]